# My KDE desktop is 'GONE' How can I recover it?

Tags: 14.04, kde

All that is left of my KDE Kubuntu 14.04 Desktop is a white background with no kicker, launcher, etc. All I get is a couple instances of `Object could not be created here` or something to that effect.

Guest account is fine, but my standard user is screwed.

What can I do, other than re-installing Kubuntu?

Comment: Try to revert the KDE settings to the default: http://askubuntu.com/questions/114807/how-to-revert-kde-to-its-default-settings

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/114807/how-to-revert-kde-to-its-default-settings

this answer helped alot

Comment: for moving you kde settings folder out of the way, as the previous comment suggest, you would want to login into a non-graphical environment. Press CTRL+ALT+F1 for that, log in, and do as suggested `mv .kde .kde_backup`. Reboot (`sudo reboot`) and you should be done.

Comment: try installing synaptic. and fix broken packages.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of reinstalling the system you could reinstall the KDE desktop environment. I'm not sure if it helps in this case though. But you may want to try reconfiguring it first by

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure kubuntu-desktop
```

Reinstall it with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop
```

Only I think this leaves the configurations, so if it doesn't work, try

```
sudo apt-get purge kubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

I hope something works for you!